# English translation of Heisenberg's paper ``Über den anschaulichen Inhalt der quantentheoretischen Kinematik und Mechanik''

Tags: quantum-mechanics, specific-reference

Is there any english translation of Heisenberg's paper *Über den anschaulichen Inhalt der quantentheoretischen Kinematik und Mechanik* online? I have found not.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google translate + Google scholar ⇒ the translation is available for free on the NASA Technical Reports Server: [The actual content of quantum theoretical kinematics and mechanics](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/search.jsp?R=19840008978).

Comment: Much appreciated, Chris (if I may call you Chris). I should have found it by myself.

Comment: As a German speaking person, I'd like to add that I find the translation "actual content" a little debatable. It sounds harsher than "anschauliche Inhalt", which could be translated to "the content which can actually be visualized (maybe opposed to that which is formal but has not clear correspondence to something real)". In particular, "actual content" implies that the other half isn't proper content, while the German expression doesn't imply that.

Comment: @NikolajK To be fair, Google translate itself said "intuitive" rather than "actual" but I only searched Scholar on the phrase "quantum theoretical kinematics and mechanics," since my ability to verify German is limited to cognates.