# How Heisenberg gave his uncertainity principle?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, history

I was just looking at the history of the [Uncertainy principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle). It is written here that

> In his celebrated $1927$ paper, "Über den anschaulichen Inhalt der quantentheoretischen Kinematik und Mechanik" ("On the Perceptual Content of Quantum Theoretical Kinematics and Mechanics"), Heisenberg established this expression as the minimum amount of unavoidable momentum disturbance caused by any position measurement,but he did not give a precise definition for the uncertainties $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p$. Instead, he gave some plausible estimates in each case separately. In his Chicago lecture he refined his principle:
> $$\Delta x\Delta p \geq h$$

I wonder if he just put his formula from out of blue. We have proof for the uncertainity principle now with the help of postulate of quantum mechanics. But you see It seems to me that quantum theory is made in such a way that uncertainity principle  can be taken care of. It's a order of magnitude $10^{-34}$ which is too small and I'm not sure how far we have measure it. I have number of questions.

Question 1: Do we know How Heisenberg gave this relation?

Question 2: How far we have gone to check this principle?

Comment: Would this be a better fit for [History of Science and Mathematics SE?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You can find a link to a translation of Heisenberg's paper on the NASA website.  There is  [a Physics SE Q&A that gives this link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/123465/english-translation-of-heisenbergs-paper-%C3%9Cber-den-anschaulichen-inhalt-der-qu).  I cannot say myself if the translation is exact or something less than that.

Comment: This would be better on [HSM](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm not asking for his paper. I'm just asking what lead him to such a precise relation.

Comment: The precision of his relation is due to Kennard and Weyl. It is the intuitive leap that's his.